# Does a Clojure proxy always invoke super.method()?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, dynamic-languages

While using [Clojure proxies](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/proxy), `fns` passed to proxy should override existing methods or are they called in conjunction with `super.method()`?

In the following code, RequestHandler.get() is invoked along with the proxy `get []`.

```
;see: http://github.com/paulosuzart/JTornado
(ns org.ctornadoweb)
(import '(org.jtornadoweb Web$RequestHandler))
(import '(org.jtornadoweb HttpServer Web$Application))


(let [myHandler (proxy [Web$RequestHandler] [] 
                  (get [] 
                    (.write "Hi CLJ"))
                  (post []
                    (.write "POST")))]

(.listen
  (HttpServer.  
    (.add (Web$Application.) "/" (class myHandler))
    false nil false) 8089))
```

The same happens to the compiled/inheritance version:

```
; Starts a JTornado HTTP Server and a sample RequestHandler.
; Bit verbose due to compilation directives. Recommendation is to generate 
; a set of macros to hide this.
(ns org.ctornadoweb
; Compiled and implements a static main method to start the server
  (:import (org.jtornadoweb HttpServer)
           (org.jtornadoweb.Web$Application)
           (org.jtornadoweb.Web$RequestHandler))
  (:gen-class :prefix "server-"))

(gen-class
 :name org.ctornadoweb.MyHandler
 :extends org.jtornadoweb.Web$RequestHandler
 :prefix "do")

(defn do-get [this]
  "Handles the HTTP GET method"
  (.write "hello clojure"))
(defn do-post [this]
  "Handles the HTTP POST method"
  (.write (.getArgument "name" "default" false)))


(defn server-main []
  "main method"
 (.listen
  (org.jtornadoweb.HttpServer.
   (.add (org.jtornadoweb.Web$Application.) "/" org.ctornadoweb.MyHandler)
     false nil false) 8089))

;use (compile 'org.ctornadoweb)
```

The trace shows the proxy get being invoked and then the super.get, what throws (by default) an exception.

```
HTTP 405: Method Not Allowed 
    at org.jtornadoweb.Web$RequestHandler.get(Web.java:72)
    at org.ctornadoweb.proxy$org.jtornadoweb.Web$RequestHandler$0.get(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to find some words about the actual behavior of Clojure Proxies. Can someone give this help?

Comment: I suspect some misuse of `proxy` on your side. `proxy` creates an *anonymous* class. So calling `class` on it is highly suspect. You should pass the object itself somewhere. If you need a class, you have to use `gen-class` with AOT compilation.

Comment: Where am I missing the point? please see http://gist.github.com/480886 Generating classes still causes the same super.method() behavior. Any idea?

Comment: You have to specify the hyphen in the prefix. `(gen-class ... :prefix do- ...)` At the moment your class doesn't see the implementations and hence calls the super ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the super method will not be called automatically, though you can explicitly call it with `proxy-super`.

The following test case shows things working as they should:

```
user=> (def foo 
         (proxy [java.util.ArrayList] [] 
           (clear [] (println "not clearing"))))
#'user/foo
user=> (.size foo)
0
user=> (.add foo "hi")
true
user=> (.add foo "bye")
true
user=> (.size foo)
2
user=> (.clear foo)
not clearing
nil
user=> (.size foo)
2
```

If `super.clear()` were getting called, the size would show as 0.